# Shell script to compare file names(without extension) in a directory

Tags: linux, shell

My requirement is I will have xml and pdf files like pairs.(e.g.,file1.xml, file1.pdf and file2.xml,file2.pdf) in same folder.

I need to check for xml files which are not having pdf pair and move them to different folder.(e.g., if file3.xml doesn't have file3.pdf, I need to move it to different folder).

Please answer me the shell script to do get this functionality done.

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow. Please show what you tried to reach your requirements. It could also be helpful that you read |HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the extension using parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in *.xml ; do
    if [[ ! -f ${file%.xml}.pdf ]] ; then
        mv "$file" folder/
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks choroba for quick reply.
But i'm very weak in shell scripting.
My requirement is I will get files like "1234.xml","1234.pdf" and "1436.xml", "1436.pdf" in folder c:/datafiles.
In this case how to check pdf pair for every xml and if we dont find the pdf pair, then we should move that particular xml file to c:/datafiles/corrupt folder.

Please give me the exact script.

Comment: Either start learning to program, or hire a programmer.